# How can I put messages or warnings into the VS error window?

Tags: visual-studio

The `Obsolete` attribute, and a few other things I've seen are able to have custom warnings or messages show in the Visual Studio IDE Error window. Is this possible with a custom attribute, preprocessor directive in C# or something else?

using Reflector to look at the Obsolete attribute didn't have any clues.

Comment: found something for warnings section, what about the messages list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#warning DEBUG is defined` - [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/963th5x3(v=VS.80).aspx)

works for warnings

Answer (score 0):

You can use the System.Diagnostics namespace.

And then call Debug.WriteLine("Some text ");

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815788

Comment: no, I mean the Error/Warning/Information window that's updating without running the project.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for.  But I use

// TODO: Blah.

That will put a todo item in your task list (not the output window) without running the solution.

Comment: yeah, but that's in a separate window, that you have to change a drop down to comments manually and remember to check instead of in the error window you look at every compile anyway.